# The distance to the marker list of google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use for placing markers on the map here is a code

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.957069, 30.323013);
GMSMarker *london2 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position2];
london2.title = @"Офис";
london2.snippet = @"Центральный офис";
london2.map = mapView_;
```

Saw the application of VTB and really want to do the same - ie Whatever view one had a map and in the second list Sarker and distance to them. How do I display a list of markers and the distance of them? For example:

[image]

Comment: There is a [distanceFromLocation()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:) method in `CLLocation` class. You can convert `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `CLLocation`, then you can calculate the distance between 2 `CLLocation` objects, you can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16852635/4195406) for sample implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps iOS SDK: Distance between east and west points on the map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852564/google-maps-ios-sdk-distance-between-east-and-west-points-on-the-map)